# Apply transaction to a grid with Server Side DataSource and sorted columns

Tags: ag-grid

I use Ag Grid with a Server Side DataSource

Concider a simple object structure Id and Name
My grid is sorted by Name
The inital grids looks like

```
+----+--------+
| ID | Name ^ |
+----+--------+
| 2  | B      |
+----+--------+
| 3  | D      |
+----+--------+
| 1  | F      |
+----+--------+
```

I have a subscription system, when an event occurs, I push new records to the grid

```js
api.applyServerSideTransaction({ 
     add: [ newRecord ]
 });
```

where the new object has Id 4 and Name E

the grid adds the new record on bottom like this, it doesn't sort the new record

```
+----+--------+
| ID | Name ^ |
+----+--------+
| 2  | B      |
+----+--------+
| 3  | D      |
+----+--------+
| 1  | F      |
+----+--------+
| 4  | E      |
+----+--------+
```

but I would expect this result

```
+----+--------+
| ID | Name ^ |
+----+--------+
| 2  | B      |
+----+--------+
| 3  | D      |
+----+--------+
| 4  | E      |
+----+--------+
| 1  | F      |
+----+--------+
```

I know there is an addIndex property, easy tu use to add to end or top, but more complicated when I need to add in the middle of the grid

Any ideas?

I tried calling refreshServerSide, OnSortChanged, applyServerSideTransaction without success

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `applyServerSideTransaction` try to use `applyTransaction`.

```
  addItems(addIndex: number | undefined) {
    const newItems = [
      createNewRowData(),
      createNewRowData(),
      createNewRowData(),
    ];
    const res = this.gridApi.applyTransaction({
      add: newItems,
      addIndex: addIndex,
    })!;
    printResult(res);
  }
```

[Ag-grid Documentation - Example: Updating with Transaction](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/data-update-transactions/#example-updating-with-transaction)

Comment: `applyTransaction` is for the ClienSide row model only, isn't it?

Comment: @mashi My understanding is that you are not updating the database through this transaction, I am recommending `applyTransaction` to update the order

Comment: `applyServerSideTransaction` has no relation to the database, it updates the row model in the browser, not on the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ServerSide row model, ag-grid has no idea how to sort your data, this is the responsibility of the server. So if sorting matters for you, instead of applying transactions I would suggest refreshing the grid.

But of course, it depends on how many updates your app is receiving, if there are too many updates, maybe there will be a sense to refresh with some debounce.

```js
const debouncedRefresh = debounce(api.refreshServerSide, 2*1000);
```